# Tracking down infinite digest errors

Tags: angularjs

We recently deployed a fairly large angularjs application which includes the ability to log errors that occur in the clients browser.  Ever since we deployed two weeks ago we can not seem to track down an infinite digest error that is occurring.

**Error Message**

```
[$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=[["fn: function (){e=h(c);var a,b;if(X(e))if(qb(e))for(d!==\nm&&(d=m,l=d.length=0,f++),a=e.length,l!==a&&(f++,d.length=l=a),b=0;b<a;b++)d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]);else{d!==k&&(d=k={},l=0,f++);a=0;for(b in e)e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(a++,d.hasOwnProperty(b)?d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]):(l++,d[b]=e[b],f++));if(l>a)for(b in f++,d)d.hasOwnProperty(b)&&!e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(l--,delete d[b])}else d!==e&&(d=e,f++);return f}; newVal: 418; oldVal: 410","$index; newVal: 28; oldVal: 29","$index; newVal: 29; oldVal: 28","$index; newVal: 70; oldVal: 69","$index; newVal: 69; oldVal: 70","$index; newVal: 78; oldVal: 79","$index; newVal: 79; oldVal: 78","$index; newVal: 94; oldVal: 95","$index; newVal: 95; oldVal: 94"],["fn: function (){e=h(c);var a,b;if(X(e))if(qb(e))for(d!==\nm&&(d=m,l=d.length=0,f++),a=e.length,l!==a&&(f++,d.length=l=a),b=0;b<a;b++)d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]);else{d!==k&&(d=k={},l=0,f++);a=0;for(b in e)e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(a++,d.hasOwnProperty(b)?d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]):(l++,d[b]=e[b],f++));if(l>a)for(b in f++,d)d.hasOwnProperty(b)&&!e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(l--,delete d[b])}else d!==e&&(d=e,f++);return f}; newVal: 426; oldVal: 418","$index; newVal: 24; oldVal: 23","$index; newVal: 23; oldVal: 24","$index; newVal: 29; oldVal: 28","$index; newVal: 28; oldVal: 29","$index; newVal: 53; oldVal: 52","$index; newVal: 52; oldVal: 53","$index; newVal: 69; oldVal: 70","$index; newVal: 70; oldVal: 69"],["fn: function (){e=h(c);var a,b;if(X(e))if(qb(e))for(d!==\nm&&(d=m,l=d.length=0,f++),a=e.length,l!==a&&(f++,d.length=l=a),b=0;b<a;b++)d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]);else{d!==k&&(d=k={},l=0,f++);a=0;for(b in e)e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(a++,d.hasOwnProperty(b)?d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]):(l++,d[b]=e[b],f++));if(l>a)for(b in f++,d)d.hasOwnProperty(b)&&!e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(l--,delete d[b])}else d!==e&&(d=e,f++);return f}; newVal: 436; oldVal: 426","$index; newVal: 23; oldVal: 24","$index; newVal: 24; oldVal: 23","$index; newVal: 28; oldVal: 29","$index; newVal: 29; oldVal: 28","$index; newVal: 33; oldVal: 32","$index; newVal: 32; oldVal: 33","$index; newVal: 70; oldVal: 69","$index; newVal: 69; oldVal: 70","$index; newVal: 89; oldVal: 88","$index; newVal: 88; oldVal: 89"],["fn: function (){e=h(c);var a,b;if(X(e))if(qb(e))for(d!==\nm&&(d=m,l=d.length=0,f++),a=e.length,l!==a&&(f++,d.length=l=a),b=0;b<a;b++)d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]);else{d!==k&&(d=k={},l=0,f++);a=0;for(b in e)e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(a++,d.hasOwnProperty(b)?d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]):(l++,d[b]=e[b],f++));if(l>a)for(b in f++,d)d.hasOwnProperty(b)&&!e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(l--,delete d[b])}else d!==e&&(d=e,f++);return f}; newVal: 442; oldVal: 436","$index; newVal: 32; oldVal: 33","$index; newVal: 33; oldVal: 32","$index; newVal: 69; oldVal: 70","$index; newVal: 70; oldVal: 69","$index; newVal: 86; oldVal: 87","$index; newVal: 87; oldVal: 86"],["fn: function (){e=h(c);var a,b;if(X(e))if(qb(e))for(d!==\nm&&(d=m,l=d.length=0,f++),a=e.length,l!==a&&(f++,d.length=l=a),b=0;b<a;b++)d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]);else{d!==k&&(d=k={},l=0,f++);a=0;for(b in e)e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(a++,d.hasOwnProperty(b)?d[b]!==e[b]&&(f++,d[b]=e[b]):(l++,d[b]=e[b],f++));if(l>a)for(b in f++,d)d.hasOwnProperty(b)&&!e.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(l--,delete d[b])}else d!==e&&(d=e,f++);return f}; newVal: 450; oldVal: 442","$index; newVal: 24; oldVal: 23","$index; newVal: 23; oldVal: 24","$index; newVal: 29; oldVal: 28","$index; newVal: 28; oldVal: 29","$index; newVal: 33; oldVal: 32","$index; newVal: 32; oldVal: 33","$index; newVal: 87; oldVal: 86","$index; newVal: 86; oldVal: 87"]]
     at ? line 6, column 449 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:6)
     at h.$digest line 101, column 152 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:101)
     at h.$apply line 103, column 100 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:103)
     at f line 67, column 98 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:67)
     at E line 71, column 117 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:71)
     at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange line 72, column 167 (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js:72)
```

**Things we know**

- We are using angularjs 1.2.7 with `ngRoute`, `bootstrap-ui`, and numerous other custom directives.
- It appears to only happen in Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread) and Kindle Fire (Silk browser)
- We can not seem to reproduce this error either in browserstack, emulator, or a physical device.
- There appears to not be isolated to a particular route.

**Question**

Is there any guidance to track the cause of this error?
Use source maps? 
Use the unmagnified version temporarily? 
Capture something else inside of angular?

Comment: Using unminified Angular will give you some easier to read results.  But I'd focus at the various newval, oldval values reported in the error- for instance these last few: "$index; newVal: 87; oldVal: 86","$index; newVal: 86; oldVal: 87" and see if you can make some sense of them- seems like a watch on `$index` may be related?  There's also a watch function that's showing up- I'd try to figure out where it's being used.  Sorry to be vague- but I'd start with all the information in that error and see if you can puzzle out what change is rippling through causing instability.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, javascript stack trace with Spy-js. You can see the call stack that was actually executed and the time it took (look for laggy/timeout):

https://github.com/spy-js/spy-js

http://spy-js.com/

Its now integrated in WebStorm with angularJS support.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/01/webstorm-8-eap/

I'd also suggest don't use any minified JS when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems - was gone after updating to latest AngularJS (1.3.15 as of now).